# Regolith - i3-wm - Background color of some text and some text colors messed up

Tags: configuration, 20.10, colors, text, i3-wm

I got Regolith-Ubuntu and I'm pretty satisfied so far. I could solve most of the issues, with the wide support including this site here. I wasn't sure, if this issue is right here or might be better on the super-user site.

I get this weird appearance in some applications like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

I suspected, that this is related to the background color, so I tried to edit ~/.config/i3/config and set the background there, but it had no effect. Preferably, I would like to edit this color only for a few applications. inkscape for example is a nightmare. If I would not have known, where the buttons are, I would be lost.

Update:
After a lot of trying, I found out, that the settings are inherited from nautilus. But this works only for seamonkey (mozilla) and gnucash. It doesn't have an effect on inkscape.

Update 2:
The issue is caused by the gtk3-themes. If I change the theme, the color changes accordingly. The reason, why inkscape was exempted, was, that inkscape chooses the theme internally. It sticks to the theme, which was selected at first run. I haven't found the value in the gtk.css-file to edit the color of the text fields, but in theory the values for changing these should be there. For now I probably have to stick to a light theme instead of a dark theme.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trying, I found the issue and solved it. In case anyone else has the same problem, here is how to fix it.

The reason for this behaviour is gtk3. To solve this, you need a light theme on your ubuntu (which is always part of the distribution). For the regular use, you can use a dark theme (like I do). If you want to change the theme for specific applications, you have to add a new alias in bash.bashrc. In my case I set it globally in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and put these lines at the end of the file:

```
alias seamonkey="GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light /opt/seamonkey/seamonkey"
alias gnucash="GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light /usr/bin/gnucash"
```

I identified the content of the commands via typing i.e. `$ type gnucash` resulting in `gnucash is /usr/bin/gnucash`. According to others I can "re-alias" the commands and don't need to know the content, but I wanted to be on the safe side.

The issue with the different behaviour of inkscape was simple. Inkscape let's you choose any gtk3-theme in the settings menu. It chooses the theme at first start and keeps it until switched manually. You can also choose "system standard" in this menu to bind it to the current theme.